# Can "this" parameter of _.apply(this,args) be be skipped?If Yes in which scenarios?

Tags: javascript

Can I skip this arguement like

```
function myFunc(arg1) {       
    //Do something 
}
myFunc.apply(['b']);
```

instead of

```
function myFunc(arg1) {       
   //Do something
}
myFunc.apply(this,['b']);
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `apply()`?

Comment: Yes,my question is in case `myFunc` is bound to  `this` object!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; that parameter is not optional.

How is the runtime supposed to know whether `['b']` is the `this` or the array of arguments?

Comment: In which scenario `this` parameter takes null value?

Comment: If the function doesn't use `this`, you can supply any value. `null` is the common placeholder.